# MVC 4 Querying Database

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and have gone through this tutorial:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view

It was pretty good at explaining of how MVC works but I need to use existing database (SQL Server) that returns all the information from the table and displays it on a web page. Does anyone know of a tutorial or example of how this is done or how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very nice tutorial to start with MVC: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Database first** approach. You can get a good number of tutorials by searching for it on google.